# Fixing Issues with FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

In my Flutter project, I am trying to implement a button click event by using FutureBuilder. Basically when the button clicked, it supposed to get the data and display in a table. So my button onPressed event handling is as below:

```
onPressed: () async{

                  if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                    _formKey.currentState.save();

                    var p = double.parse(loanAmount);
                    var r = double.parse(interestRate);
                    var n = int.parse(monthes);

                    Api api = new Api();

                    new FutureBuilder<List>(
                      future: api.calculateEmi(p, r, n),
                      builder: (BuildContext buildContext, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {

                        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                        } else {

                          print( snapshot.data);

                          return new SingleChildScrollView(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: DataTableWidget(listOfColumns: snapshot.data.map(
                              (e)=>{
                                'Month': e['Month'],
                                'Principal': e['Principal'],
                                'InterestP': e['InterestP'],
                                'PrinciplaP': e['PrinciplaP'],
                                'RemainP': e['RemainP']

                              }).toList()
                              ),
                          ); 
                        }

                      }
                      );


                  }
                }
```

The Api call is working and the method calculateEmi is called and get data returned ( a List of Map), but the view just not updated and no table appeared at all, and I use breakpoint at the builder portion but it never go into it, where did I do wrong, can anyone help? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FutureBuilder` needs to be inserted somewhere in the flutter widget tree. Simply creating a new `FutureBuilder` doesn't tell flutter what to do with it.

I'm guessing you instead want to put the `FutureBuilder` you created somewhere in the parent widget of the `onPressed` method. If you need it to only show when the button is pressed you can do that with a `bool` that determines whether to show the `FutureBuilder` or not.

Ex.

```
Widget build(context) {
  if(buttonPressed) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      ...
    );
  }
  else {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, do you have sample code to do the bool check in FutureBuilder?

Comment: @Derrick.X I added an example. The biggest issue is that the `FutureBuilder` is not being built anywhere.